# Losing data when converting from UIImage to Mat

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage, computer-vision

I am trying to use an HSV threshold to find a red cup in an image. One of my implementations uses the cvVideoCamera delegate and gets a mat straight from the camera. My other implementation lets the user record the video then we extract the frames using AVFoundation for processing.

When I threshold the image from AVFoundation I get nothing back besides a black image.

Here is my code:

`inRange(gray, Scalar(114, 135, 135), Scalar(142, 255, 255), dst);`

The first image is an example of an image that works properly and the second is an image from AVFoundation which does not threshold how I expect, it produces an all black image.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why the second image produces different results when the color of the cup looks quite similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image pulled from a video is reconstructed in a manner that depends on the video's encoding and compression codec. Short version is that unless you happen to pick out a keyframe (which you generally won't have an api to do, so trying to do this isn't viable), you're getting a image that is reconstructed from the video.

So a image taken from the  video from same time that you took a straight-up image from the camera (assuming you could do both at the same time) would be different. After any sort processing you'll, of course, get different result.

Before applying your threshold, get the raw image for before approaches. Look at them (or a delta of them) and you'll see that just aren't the same image. The second approach will likely have introduced artifacts from being encoded into video from multiple frames, then reconstructed into a single frame image.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this issue, use OpenCV Native conversion functions.

```
 #import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>

UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& image);
void UIImageToMat(const UIImage* image,
                         cv::Mat& m, bool alphaExist = false);
```